# Rigging eyes parented to armature offset

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I have an armature and two eye balls objects, and I created the eye bones eye.L/R to have their tail in the center of the eye object, and parented the eyes to the bones, but at some point, it got offset.

The most weird thing is that the eyes appear at a different Z-value, even though the bones are exactly in the same spot, and the eyes real Z-values are identical.

If I unparent the eyes from the bones, they snap into exactly where I want them.

I have some IK and eye targets going on, but that doesn't seem to affect this.

What did I do wrong?

Please see the blend file: [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier and correct way to do it is using the `Copy Location` object constraint as shown below:

[image]

this will fix your problem.

I noticed also that your Pose Position is different from your Rest Position, where the bones are rotated. To make the eyes roll with the bones I added a `Copy Rotation` as shown below:

[image]

This is the end result:

In Rest Position:

[image]

In Pose Position:

[image]

Updated .blend file can be found here: [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, also for noticing the pose position, the eye rig now works great :)

Comment: @Niclas No worries, glad I was able to help :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I should post this as a new question, but I'm also trying to limit rotation, so it's not able to look in weird angles. The Limit rotation on X works fine, but on Z it's not acting as I expect. I added the constraint to the eyeballs. Do you know why?

Comment: @Niclas yes, it's better to post a new question and mention all the steps you did with screenshots. Then show the problem and provide a .blend file

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, i will stop spamming this question, and follow your tips on future questions. :)